# Instantiate request scoped bean in scheduled executor without any HTTP request

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, scheduledexecutorservice

In a JSF 2.2 webapp, I have a scheduled thread executor service that periodically executes some code which needs to instantiate a request scoped bean to perform some tasks. How do I instantiate a request scoped bean without any http requests from any client but from within an application scoped bean.

When I try :

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{namesDirectory}", NamesDirectory.class)
```

where `NamesDirectory` is a request scoped bean, I get `NullPointerException`

Comment: that sounds wrong to me, you shouldn't use request scope associated beans for your logic outside of request

Answer (score 1):

You should not rely on a managed bean for the task. Managed beans (regardless their scope) are used for request/response cycles and that's **their only job**. Any business logic should be handled in service classes like EJB's, CDI, Spring beans, beans from another framework or plain Java classes that work as service layer.